# Is it bad practice to return all results when an argument is left out?

Tags: graphql

I'm fairly new to the concept of GraphQL and I'm wondering whether it is considered bad practice to return all results in a query when the argument is left out.

If, for example, I run this query:

```
query {
  item(title: "test") {
    title,
    properties {
      key,
      value
     }
   }
}
```

It will return all properties, but if I run this query:

```
query {
  item(title: "test") {
    title,
    properties(group: "test-group") {
      key,
      value
     }
   }
}
```

It will return all properties in the "test-group".
I tried searching for this question online and on StackOverflow but I couldn't find the answer I need.

I did manage to find the following example on the GraphQL website though, but I'm not sure whether it's exactly the same:

```
{
  human(id: "1000") {
    name
    height
  }
}
```

```
{
  human(id: "1000") {
    name
    height(unit: FOOT)
  }
}
```

If anyone could shed some light on this, I'd be very thankful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on if an item can possibly has many properties that has a chance to cause the server to run out of memory if multiple users retrieves an item 's all properties at the same time. If the chance is very very very small , it is very normal to just returning all properties if user left out the properties field 's argument.

Otherwise , it is not so good to always returning all properties due to the chance to bring down the server because of running out of memory. In this case, you can apply some sensible default to return only the first N-th properties to prevent it from happening.

It is equivalent to the REST API that returning a list of records. If an user does not specify the query parameter for pagination , it will by default return a sensible number of records but not returning all records.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Accepted your answer.